R data frame count consecutive days with condition = 0
I would like to count the maximum number of consecutive rows = 0 per year, for each column of the data frame.
I try this but it works for each column separately:
library(data.table)

data <- data.frame(YEAR = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4),
                   PREC1 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 4, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 8, 0),
                   PREC2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 1),
                   PREC3 = c(0, 0, 12, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                   PREC4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 9, 8, 0, 0),
                   PREC5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 7, 1, 0, 1),
                   PREC6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 9, 6, 9, 0),
                   PREC7 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 2, 4, 1),
                   PREC8 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0),
                   PREC9 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0),
                   PREC10 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0),
                   PREC11 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 7, 2, 0),
                   PREC12 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 9, 2, 0))

df=data
setDT(df)

df[, Consec_Days := seq_len(.N),rleid(PREC1 == 0)]
df[PREC1 != 0, Consec_Days := NA]
df=na.omit(df)
head(df)

library(plyr)
CDD = ddply(df, .(YEAR), summarize, 
            Prec = max(Consec_Days));CDD


How to do this for all columns of the data frame simultaneously?

The answer is always rle()

One option with dplyr could be:
data %>%
 summarise(across(starts_with("PREC"), ~ with(rle(. == 0), max(lengths[values]))), 
           .by = YEAR)

  YEAR PREC1 PREC2 PREC3 PREC4 PREC5 PREC6 PREC7 PREC8 PREC9 PREC10 PREC11 PREC12
1    1     3     4     2     4     4     4     3     3     3      3      3      3
2    2     2     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4      4      4      5
3    3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3      3      3      3
4    4     1     2     5     2     1     1     1     2     2      2      2      2


Sorry but I'm a R beginner.
The code didn't work:
Error in across():
! Must only be used inside data-masking verbs like mutate(),
filter(), and group_by().
Run rlang::last_trace()

Try to update dplyr to its most recent version :)

Using grouping by YEAR and then picking the max value of the rle output.
library(data.table)

df[, lapply(.SD, \(x) {
       res <- rle(x == 0)
       max(res$lengths[res$values])}), by = YEAR]

output
    YEAR PREC1 PREC2 PREC3 PREC4 PREC5 PREC6 PREC7 PREC8 PREC9 PREC10 PREC11
   <num> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int>  <int>
1:     1     3     4     2     4     4     4     3     3     3      3      3
2:     2     2     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4      4      4
3:     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3      3      3
4:     4     1     2     5     2     1     1     1     2     2      2      2
   PREC12
    <int>
1:      3
2:      5
3:      3
4:      2

Data
df <- structure(list(YEAR = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3,
3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), PREC1 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 4,
2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 8, 0), PREC2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 1), PREC3 = c(0, 0, 12, 1,
3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PREC4 = c(0,
0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 9, 8, 0, 0), PREC5 = c(0,
0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 7, 1, 0, 1), PREC6 = c(0,
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 9, 6, 9, 0), PREC7 = c(1,
0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 2, 4, 1), PREC8 = c(0,
0, 0, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0), PREC9 = c(0,
0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0), PREC10 = c(0,
0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0), PREC11 = c(0,
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 7, 2, 0), PREC12 = c(0,
0, 0, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 9, 2, 0)), 
class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))

